# Lerp function returns NaN

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

I do lerps all the time but lately been having this issue where lerp function (inside the `animIt` function below) is returning a `NaN`. Console log reveals that the returned value from `lerp()` is inded a number. I've tried a lot of stuff including `parseFloat` and `toFixed(0)` but to no avail. Could someone please help me understand what's wrong? I am unable to proceed in my project. Thanks.

```
  function lerp(start, end, t){
      return (1-t)*start+t*end
  }

  let currentX = 0, currentY = 0;
  
  let cursorContainer = document.querySelector('#irbrkj');
  
  let observer1 = new IntersectionObserver( function(el, observer) {

      el.forEach( (entry) => {

        if(entry.isIntersecting){
          
          document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', (e) => {    
            offX = e.offsetX;
            offY = e.offsetY;    
                })
          
          function animIt(){
           currentX = lerp(currentX, offX, 0.3 );
           currentY = lerp(currentY, offY, 0.3 );  
            
           // These are showing NaN
           console.log(currentX);
           console.log(currentY);
        
   
            cursorContainer.style.setProperty('--cursorTop', currentY + 'px');
            cursorContainer.style.setProperty('--cursorLeft', currentX + 'px');
            
            requestAnimationFrame(animIt);
          }      
          
          animIt();
        }
      })

    }, {
   threshold: 0.2
    });

  observer1.observe(cursorContainer);
```

Comment: could it just be that *animIt* is called before the event listener that sets the *offX*  and *offY* is called for the first time and they are thus uninitialized ?

Comment: I would add a `console.log(start, end, t)` on the first line of `lerp()`, and check what's being passed in. The calculation being done will result in a number unless one of those parameters isn't a number (or, isn't able to be parsed into a number)

Comment: Thanks guys, but I found the issue and corrected it. The `offX` and `offY` didn't have a starting value when I defined them with a `let`

Comment: @Mr.Coder - that's what I meant with my comment ;-)

Comment: @MBobrik I am so sorry I didn't read the entire comment as I was writing my answer that time. It's ok though, you can submit this as an answer and I will accept it if SO allows. Or atleast will upvote it just in case :)

Answer (score 0):

OK got it!
So when I defined `offX` and `offY`, they didn't have a value, so I defined them as `let offX = 0, offY = 0` and now `lerp()` has a starting 0 to work with. Hope this helps others.